# Unable to print wanted variable (outputting unwanted information)

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to print what the user enters in the tkinter window but am printing entire columns from my excel file, information about rows and columns and error messages when trying to simply `print(A)`, `print(SeriesA)` and `print(entry1)`. The code works perfectly fine imputing the entries into excel but when trying to print them into cmd/pycharm I can't figure out what is actually needed. (I need to figure this out in order to add into a dictionary. (NOTE: This is not my code, this is code similar to mine but borrowed off the internet as it is clearer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w36yng8BTUU - Derrick Sherril 29/09/2020)

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

def submit_fields():
    path = 'E:\subjects,classes,teachers.xlsx'
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    SeriesA = df1['Operator']
    SeriesB = df1['Number']
    A = pd.Series(entry1.get())
    B = pd.Series(entry2.get())
    SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
    SeriesB = SeriesB.append(B)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Operator":SeriesA, "Number":SeriesB})
    df2.to_excel(path, index=False)
    entry1.delete(0, END)                 #Removes entered words
    entry2.delete(0, END)                 #Removes entered words

master = Tk()

Label(master, text="Operator").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Number").grid(row=1)

entry1 = Entry(master)
entry2 = Entry(master)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3,column=0, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Submit', command=submit_fields).grid(row=3,column=1, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried this without tkinter?

Comment: Hey mate, appreciate the feedback but the problem is I am using tkinter because the software I am making requires a user interface.

Comment: Yes i understand, i was asking if the logic works, then the problem with tkinter can be solved, pretty much i dont see any mistakes, but ya, also can you elaborate on what your trying to get?

Comment: Oh okay, I understand where your coming from with problem solving and recoding. So pretty much there are two entry boxes in the tkinter window - Operator and number. Once you click submit they are added into an excel file. My question is, is there a way to get those answers and print them in the terminal.

Comment: As i was not sure of what type of xlsx file or how its formatted, i used a csv file and changed the code accordingly, it worked then, i was able to see the changes on the file and on the terminal too. Add this to the end of the function `print(pd.read_excel(path))`

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it

Comment: Hey mate, I've just tried to run the code with the print at the end, and it prints everything (as in all my inputs) is there a way to single out say the first input and second input? And or inputs in the first row or second row?

Comment: **I have also tried using ``` print(pd.read_excel(path).grid(row=2)) ``` but that just comes up with an error ** Because my main goal was to find out how the inputs were being created so I can add them into a dictionary. I'm not sure how I can get the inputs from a Tkinter window into a dictionary. Thank you for your help anyway and so far.

Comment: I think you have to store each row of data from the dataframe in a variable and then use `Label()` and `grid()` those labels on to the rows or whatever